# Why is my recursive function in racket giving me a 0 for every parameter I pass in

Tags: list, recursion, racket

```
(define (getmyLastt 1st)
  (if (null? 1st)
      "empty list"  
      (getmyLastt (cdr 1st))))
```

I want the output to be the last element in a list but for some reason it only outputs a 0. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not giving you `0`, but `"empty list"` for every parameter you pass. the reason is simple:

```
(getmylastt '()) ; ==> "empty list"
```

And

```
(getmylastt '(1)) ; ==> (getmylastt (cdr '(1)))
```

So it iterates the whole list until you are at the empty list in which the result of the recursion is `"empty list"`. The functions just follows the orders.

For a `last` implementation you usually have an extra case where you check if the `cdr` is not `pair?` and if so you are at the last pair. eg.

```
(getmylastt '(1 3)) ; ==> 
(getmylastt '(3))   ; ==> 
'(3)
```